# Why was my root certificate not updated

Tags: ubuntu, certificates

LetsEncrypt migrated their root certificate from I believe `DST Root CA X3` to `ISRG Root X1` (at least 5 years ago I believe). The `DST Root CA X3` certificate expired on 1-Oct-2021.

I have two Ubuntu 20.04 workstations, both began life as 18.04 and were upgraded. On one (my home machine) all was fine, I could access websites after DST Root CA X3 expired.

However, on my work machine, I could not. Specifically PostGres sql's PPA (https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal) - when I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` it returned an expired certificate error.

Running `sudo update-ca-certificates` fixed the problem - `apt-get` could download the latest pgadmin4.

Edit: based on the comments, it seems that `sudo update-ca-certificates` removed the expired certificate, and possible installed the new one but I would have thought that was already installed.

My question is why did one machine have the correct certificate installed and the other didn't. I would have assumed that Ubuntu 18.04+ would have shipped with `ISRG Root X1` since I believe LetsEncrpyt have used that certificate for 5 years. And are you expected to run `update-ca-certificates` yourself?

I work for a small startup in a co-location work space. So it's essentially a BYO device that isn't managed by IT, but it does connect to the internet via a wireless network managed by the co-location manager. I wonder if that was a factor but I doubt it.

Comment: ISRG X1 root was _created_ in 2015, but LE didn't 'migrate' to it (for default use) until they reached 'sufficient' distribution in default truststores (of devices, systems, and things like Java) which was this spring. But yes Ubuntu18.04 (which I still have running unupgraded) does have ISRG X1. You say accessing 'websites' from the home machine works -- is that with a browser, or something using OpenSSL? Only programs using OpenSSL below 1.1.0 still 'see' the expired DST root when the ISRG root is available, apparently including apt.

Comment: Oh, and the DST expiration was Sep-30 14:01:15 UTC. The Qs on Stack started well before Oct-01 :-(

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `sudo apt-get update` worked on the home machine but not the work one. By worked I mean didn't generate expired certificate errors for https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal

Comment: From memory (I'm not at work) running `update-ca-certificates` removed expired certificates. So I guess if apt was using the expired one then removing it might make it start using ISRG

Comment: If it is (directly or indirectly) using OpenSSL 1.0.2, and it probably is if it had the problem, then yes removing the DST root causes OpenSSL to correctly find the ISRG root instead.